# Strange behavior with setTimeout and Promise in Jest test

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, jestjs

I have encountered a problem when writing a unit test around an `async` function using `setTimeout`. Here's the simplified version:

```
var counter = 0;
const sut = async () => {
   await Promise.resolve("Task A");   
   await Promise.resolve("Task B");
   counter++;
   setTimeout(() => sut(), 100);
}

// unit test with Jest:
it('Test', async () => {
   jest.useFakeTimers();
   await sut();
   jest.advanceTimersToNextTimer();
   await Promise.resolve();
   await Promise.resolve(); // without this repeated await, the test fails!!
   expect(counter).toBe(2);
}
```

Suprisingly, in my unit test, I have to `await` on a resolved `Promise` two times i.e. equal to the number of times I `await` in `sut`.
I cannot explain this. My assumption was it would be enough to make sure micro-task queue is used up in order to advance testing flow.

Can someone shed a light here please?

Comment: `sut()` will queue twice. `await sut()` will wait both but if you want to wait for the *next* execution to finish, you also need to wait both microtasks inside `sut()` to finish. Note that this test is going to be extremely brittle, as you are testing internal implementation and might even be affected by environmental stuff.

Comment: @VLAZ I still don't get why `await Promise.resolve()` doesn't come after two microtasks! Anyhow, I don't wish to test internal implementation. All I want to achieve here is to check the value of `counter`  after some milliseconds or after a few rounds if it's easier. What's your suggestion?

Comment: The problem is that `sut` is not easily unit testable. To more easily facilitate the tests, I'd break it up. One function will do the counting, the other the scheduling of executions. So you can test whether each execution of `sut_counter()` increments the count and then be able to test if `sut_scheduler()` schedules `sut_counter()` to be run every 100ms. You can mock the `sut_counter()` for the latter, so you don't have to wait for any tasks.

Comment: @VLAZ This is a simplified version. In real case scenario, `sut_counter` is an `async` function which may take any random time say 200ms.

Comment: Yes, hence you want to check if that works in isolation. You'd do `await sut_counter(); await sut_counter(); expect(counter).toBe(2);` and be assured that the counting part works. And then you'd test `sut_scheduler()` with a mock of `sut_counter()` which has a predictable behaviour in order to verify that the scheduling part works, as well.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, thanks. Alternatively, I'm thinking about simply `await`ing for a long-enough time frame in the test, instead of messing with Timers.

Comment: That's still brittle. Let's say you wait for 450ms. That can increment the timer anywhere between 1 and 3 times, depending on how long the tasks in `sut` take. And if you determine that *now* it increments twice, so you check for that, then in the future the tasks might change and take less or more time. So when you wait for 450ms you might get a different number of increments.

Comment: @VLAZ Sure! I should've mentioned that I would mock tasks in `sut` and also parameterize `delay` of `setTimeout`. In this case, I think everything will be under control.